# I have 100 images called m1-m100 in matlab. How do you create a loop that resizes each image?

Tags: image, matlab, loops, matrix, image-resizing

The script that I have at the moment brings in all the photos I have in my directory and saves them in my works space as m1, m2, m3 ...... m100 since I have 100 images. Heres the code:

```
A=dir; 
for n=3:length(A)   %it starts with 3 because the first 2 entries in the dir are . and ..
eval(['m' num2str(n) '=imread(A(n).name);']);
end
```

Nice and simple! However, I now want to go to each of the images and resize them but I am having to do it manually at the moment and I was wondering if anyone knew how to create a function that would loop through all the image matrices (first m1 then m2 and so on) and resize each one. They all need to be the size of the first image. This is what I have so far but it takes a long time and I am hoping to load in more images in the future:

```
[a b c]=size(m1);
p1=m1
p2 = imresize(m2, [a b]);
p3 = imresize(m3, [a b]);
p4 = imresize(m4, [a b]);
p5 = imresize(m5, [a b]);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it with your own code : (almost)

```
A=dir; 
a= ...; b= ...;
for n=3:length(A)   %it starts with 3 because the first 2 entries in the dir are . and ..
eval(['mresized' num2str(n) '=imresize(imread(A(n).name),[a b]);']);
end
```

Comment: Hi Natan

Thanks for the help, thats great, worked perfectly and doesn't take too long for the compter to run. 

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You could do it easily with cell arrays as following

```
A=dir; 
img = cell(length(A)-2,1);
img_rz = cell(length(A)-2,1);
for n=3:length(A)   
    img{n} = imread(A(n).name);
    img_rz{n} = imresize(img{n},[a b]);
end
```